# ResponseBodyAdvice for Thymeleaf response

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

**TLDR; Is there a way to write a ResponseBodyAdvice for responses coming from Thymeleaf template engine?**

For a "normal" endpoint annotated with @RequestMapping and @ResponseBody, I can write a ResponseBodyAdvice to modify / handle the response before it's written to the output stream. Now, is there a way to do the same thing with an endpoint returning the name of a template view (Thymeleaf in this case)?

Example that works:

```
@Controller
public class MyController
{
    @GetMapping("/path")
    @ResponseBody
    public String dispatch(final HttpServletRequest request,
                           final HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception
    {
        return "my output string...";
    }
}

@ControllerAdvice
public class MyControllerAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<String>
{
    @Override
    public boolean supports(final MethodParameter returnType,
                            final Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType)
    {
        // This is called
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String beforeBodyWrite(final String body,
                                  final MethodParameter returnType,
                                  final MediaType selectedContentType,
                                  final Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType,
                                  final ServerHttpRequest request,
                                  final ServerHttpResponse response)
    {
        // This is called

        // Perform the response logic...
        return body;
    }
}
```

Example that does NOT work:

```
@Controller
public class MyController
{
    @GetMapping("/path")
    public String dispatch(final HttpServletRequest request,
                           final HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception
    {
        return "viewName"; // will be resolved to a view by the templating engine (Thymeleaf) - typically viewName.html - and evaluated
    }
}

@ControllerAdvice
public class MyControllerAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object>
{
    @Override
    public boolean supports(final MethodParameter returnType,
                            final Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType)
    {
        // This is never called

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(final Object body,
                                  final MethodParameter returnType,
                                  final MediaType selectedContentType,
                                  final Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType,
                                  final ServerHttpRequest request,
                                  final ServerHttpResponse response)
    {
        // This is never called

        // Perform the response logic...
        return body;
    }
}
```

It's hard to tell whether the above controller advice simply isn't being matched to the output of the template engine or whether there is a controller advice for a more specific type being selected in it's place...

Regards,
Blasphemic

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using a `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`:

```
public class MyResponseInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter 
{
    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, 
                           HttpServletResponse response, 
                           Object handler, 
                           ModelAndView modelAndView) 
        throws Exception 
    {
        // Your logic here, which will be called after the controller method returns
    }
}
```

You will also need to add this class to your `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`:

```
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addInterceptor(new MyResponseInterceptor());
    }
```

Note that this has the opposite problem in that it will NOT work with Controller methods that return a `ResponseBody` directly

Comment: I tried this but it intercepts after the controller but before thymeleaf thereby not answering the original question, sorry. Also used `WebMvcConfigurer` as `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated.